# left join returning more than expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the following query

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

`table1` returns 16 rows and `table2` returns 35 rows.

I was expecting the above query to return 16 rows because of the `left join`, but it is returning 35 rows.  `right join` also returns 35 rows

Why is this happening and how do I get it to return 16 rows?

Comment: Are the extra rows returning with null values?

Comment: If there's a link between all the name in the tbl1 and the rows in tbl2, the query will return 35 rows.

Comment: I'd say the relationship between `table` and `table2` is *one-to-many*. Is this the case?

Comment: @oshirowanen in that case, you will need to supply more conditions specifying how you expect the results to be limited

Comment: Without seeing the data, it's hard to give you a full answer. However, it sounds like at least some of your 16 rows in `table1` are linking to more than one row in `table2`.

Comment: @Phil, basically, if table1 contains 1 name as 'oshirowanen' and table2 contains 3 names as 'oshirowanen', those 3 should be counted as 1 in table2.  I thought a left join would do that, but clearly I thought wrong.

Comment: @oshirowanen, how do you expect mysql to "count 3 rows as 1"?

Comment: They are three different rows with three different sets of data, how do you want them to be collapsed? Mysql can group them and run aggregate functions, but you need to specify first how the aggregates are supposed to work.

Comment: @oshirowanen "as 1" what? You'll have to give some examples of data from both tables and what you expect the query result to look like.

Comment: @Ben Lee, I thought if the join had 1 from the left and 3 from the right, it would count it as 1 join.

Comment: @oshirowanen, no. Left join returns one copy from table 1 for each copy in table2.

Comment: Because `Table2` has multiple records with the same name field.

Comment: Yes, and I want a one-to-one assignment according to certain parameters

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LEFT JOIN can return multiple copies of the data from table1, if the foreign key for a row in table 1 is referenced by multiple rows in table2.

If you want it to only return 16 rows, one for each table 1 row, and with a random data set for table 2, you can use just a plain GROUP BY:

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
group by table1.name
```

`GROUP BY` aggregates rows based on a field, so this will collapse all the table1 duplicates into one row. Generally, you specify aggregate functions to explain how the rows should collapse (for example, for a number row, you could collapse it using SUM() so the one row would be the total). If you just want one random row though, don't specify any aggregate functions. MySQL will by default just choose one row (note that this is specific to MySQL, most databases will require you to specify aggregates when you group). The way it chooses it is not technically "random", but it is not necessarily predictable to you. I guess by "random" you really just mean "any row will do".

Comment: A random row from table2, as long as name from table1 matches name from table2.

Comment: Agreed: The OP needs to show us both the source data being used and the output that is desired.

Comment: @oshirowanen, I updated to explain how to get just 16 rows, choosing a single row for each table2 association.

Comment: @BenLee Thanks for information, didn't know about such MySQL behavior.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev, note that I just clarified the details. MySQL will not return a random row by default, but it will return a single row by default, and not necessarily in a predictable way. So if you just "any row will do", you can use this method. If you actually need a truly random row, that's a much more complex query.

Comment: Tip: I added a unique auto increment field to use in the GROUP BY statement. This was because the left table in the join didn't have a single unique field.

Comment: The problem may be when you need to have all the results ordered by a fieldX in table2, but grouped by fieldY in table1. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @decadenza do you actually need to `order` by fieldX in table2? Or would a simple aggregation function do? For example, if you are looking to find the row with first alphabetical `table2.name` but grouped by a row on table1, you can select the aggregate `MIN(table2.name)`. Similar for other data types besides strings.

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume you have the following tables:

```
tbl1:
|Name |
-------
|Name1|
|Name2|

tbl2:
|Name |Value |
--------------
|Name1|Value1|
|Name1|Value2|
|Name3|Value1|
```

For your LEFT JOIN you'll get:

```
|tbl1.Name|tbl2.Name|Value |
----------------------------
|Name1    | Name1   |Value1|
|Name1    | Name1   |Value2|
|Name2    | NULL    | NULL |
```

So, LEFT JOIN means that all records from LEFT (first) table will be returned regardless of their presence in right table.

For your question you need to specify some specific fields instead of using "*" and add `GROUP BY tbl1.Name` - so your query will look like

```
select tbl1.Name, SOME_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(tbl2.specific_field), ...
from table1
left join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
GROUP BY tbl1.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to use this is by using the power of SQL distinct.

```
select distinct tbl1.id, *
from table1 tbl1
left join table2 tbl2 on tbl2.name = tbl1.name

where
 ....................
```

Please not that I am also using aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

Duplication may be reason. See example in the post
https://alexpetralia.com/posts/2017/7/19/more-dangerous-subtleties-of-joins-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

If the name column is not unique in the tables then you may simply have duplicates on table2.

Try running:

```
select * from table2 where name not in (select name from table1);
```

If you get no results back then duplicates on the name column is the reason for the extra rows coming back.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to join the single latest/earliest relative row from right table, you can limit the join data using `min/max primary key` and then `limiting to 1 row using group` Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(tbl2_primary_col), {table2.etc} FROM table2 GROUP BY name) AS tbl2
    ON table1.name = tbl2.name
WHERE {condition_for_table1}
```

And remember don't use * for left join because it will disable min/max and always return first row.

Answer (score -2):

As per your comment "A random row from table2, as long as name from table1 matches name from table2", you can use the following:

```
select table1.name, (select top 1 somecolumn from table2 where table2.name = table1.name)
from table1
```

Note that top 1 is not mysql but it is for SQL Server

Comment: MySQL uses `LIMIT`. Also, where's the randomness?